# PowerShell Error - Scheduled Task - expression expected

Tags: powershell, expression, scheduled-tasks, quotes

I am setting up scheduled tasks for logging off disconnected sessions.  I setup the task with the action of opening PowerShell.exe with the argument shown below

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -command "Invoke-command -ScriptBlock {quser | Select-String "Disc" | ForEach {logoff ($_.tostring() -split " +")[2]}}"`

The argument works by itself in PowerShell but when I try to create this task it fails with the error:

```
powershell.exe : At line:1 char:89
At line:2 char:1
+ powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -command "Invoke-co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (At line:1 char:89:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ ...  {quser | Select-String  Disc | ForEach {logoff (((.tostring() -split ...
+                                                                  ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

I believe that I need to have the expression evaluated for the string to populate correctly and have tried escaping both quotes and parentheses to try to get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like to me that ($_.tostring() -split ' +')[2] is not being understood as an expression from the pipeline object coming from quser. Still doing some testing.

Comment: powershell.exe -command "(quser | select-string 'Disc').count" returns a count of objects but powershell.exe -command "quser | select-string 'Disc' | foreach-object {$_} returns no objects.  I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are probably the quotes. Mind you have to properly quote and escape your command line arguments. You can use single quotes inside your command for simplicity, or skip them alltogether if not needed. Also, the `Invoke-Command` is redundant.

Try this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "quser | Select-String Disc | foreach {logoff ($_.Line -split ' +')[2]}"
```

Comment: If I try and run "quser | Select-String 'Disc' | ForEach {logoff ($_.tostring() -split ' +')[2]}" it works and displays the disconnected session.  When I run powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -command "quser | Select-String 'Disc' | ForEach {logoff ($_.tostring() -split ' +')[2]}" which you suggested I still get same error "an expression was expected after '('"

Comment: Thanks for your help about invoke-command.  Should have been more obvious to me that it was redundant.

Comment: Solved it by escaping variables and using scriptblock code below.  Sorry for formatting: Powershell.exe –executionpolicy bypass –noprofile –command “Invoke-command –scriptblock {

`$ints = (quser | select-string ‘Disc’).linenumber

`$ints | foreach-object {

&logoff `$_

}}”